# How to download files in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I have an application which downloads an image from the NASA APOD. I have tried stream and DownloadManager but it just does not work.

Here is my current code.

```
private void download(String url) {
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

I then call the method in a buttonClick:

```
normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        download("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0611/ngc6745_hst.jpg");
    }
});
```

This code doesn't show anything; no error and no notification. While the stream method I tried before gives me FileNotFoundException even though I created a new file using File.createNewFile(). Any help or suggestion are appreciated.

This is my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>`
```

My device runs in Android 11(API 30).

**UPDATE**

I change my download method above to:

```
private void download(String title, String url) throws IOException {
    File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
    }
    
    File fileName = new File(directory,title);
    
    if(!fileName.exists()){
        fileName.createNewFile();
    }

    URL u = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

    if (connect.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Log.w("ERROR SERVER RETURNED HTTP", connect.getResponseCode() + "");
    }

    try (InputStream is = connect.getInputStream();
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        int b = 0;

        while ((b = is.read(bytes, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fos.write(bytes, 0, b);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the download is stored at /data/com.example.myapp/DCIM/.

Comment: Please put full url in your code.

Comment: Use setDestinationInExternalFilesDir.

Comment: Hello I already tried setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() before it does not work.

Comment: `problem is the download is stored at /data/com.example.myapp/DCIM/` Why is that a problem? You programmed it that way.

Comment: I wanted the downloaded files to be in the outer dcim or pictures directory

Comment: What is an outer directory?

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() does not deliver a path like  /data/......

Comment: Storage/emulated/0/DCIM Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: No. getExternalFilesDir() will not deliver that path either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but download manager does not work for me it only create directory in the data/mypackage and never download the file.If any one can fix this please tell me so that I don't have to worry about ui notification.

For now this is my code that works:

```
private void download(String title, String url) throws IOException {
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/"+getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getApplicationInfo()));

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
    }
    
    File fileName = new File(directory,title);
    
    if(!fileName.exists()){
        fileName.createNewFile();
    }

    URL u = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

    if (connect.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Log.w("ERROR SERVER RETURNED HTTP", connect.getResponseCode() + "");
    }

    try (InputStream is = connect.getInputStream();
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        int b = 0;

        while ((b = is.read(bytes, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fos.write(bytes, 0, b);
        }
    }
}
```

That Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is deprecated though.

Comment: `download manager does not work for me it only create directory` You are creating that directory with mkdir().

Comment: Yes but it never download the file in the url